# Prevent bing from crawling thousands of essentially identical pages?

Tags: web-crawlers, canonical-url, bingbot

I have a web page with a dozen tables of data on it, each with half a dozen columns.  Every table can be sorted by a column by clicking on the relevant header, and these get appended to the querystring.

e.g. a page with three tables sorted by column 4, 6, and descending 3:

```
page.html?s1=4&s2=6&s3=-3
```

etc.

I have nofollow links on the column headers, and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="page.html">
```

on the page.

But bing still crawls its way through thousands of combinations.  5772 of them yesterday!

I've marked s1/s2/s3/s4... as parameters to ignore (a long time ago), but that's not helped.

How can I prevent it from doing this?  It's unnecessary server load for no gain.

Comment: I am thinking that Bing has to crawl these to know what applies. I would be less concerned over the crawl and more concerned if these show up in the SERPs.

Comment: I don't buy that. It has all the facts it needs to know not to crawl those pages before it crawls them...

Answer (score 1):

You could tell Bing, and other webcrawlers, what to spider and what to ignore using a file called robots.txt in the root of your website.

You can tell specific or all crawlers to ignore specific urls.

in your case

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*?s1=*&s2=*&s3=*
```

you might need to make small changes in the Disallow line depending on the parameters used in your site.

More on robots.txt files [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/)